Restrictions on Polynomial Interpolation Between Derivatives
If you have a a list if length $n$ of ordered triples of the form $(x, y, k)$ what are the restrictions on $x$, $y$, and $k$ such that there is exactly one polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n - 1$ such that for each ordered pair the $k$th derivative of $f$ passes through the point $(x, y)$?
The restrictions I have been able to come up with are the following:

No pairs of $x$ and $k$ can repeat so that $f$ can be a function.
All values of $k$ must be less than $n$ otherwise either $f$ would have to have a nonzero $n$th derivative when it only has a degree of $n - 1$ or there would be an infinite number of polynomials that pass through the points.
For all of the ordered pairs, the points $(x, y)$ must be able to be interpolated by a $n - k - 1$ degree polynomial. This means that either any value of $k$ cannot repeat more than $n - k$ times or that the points must make up a special case where they can be interpolated by a $n - k - 1$ degree polynomial.
There must be one instance where $k = 0$ so it is possible to find the constant term of $f$

Are these only restrictions? If these conditions are satisfied is the linear system of equations of the coefficients guaranteed to be solvable and to have only 1 solution? Are there other restrictions I have not considered?

A "3-element ordered pair" is self-contradictory.  An "ordered triple" is probably what you want.

The "best" Answer is probably this: each triple yields an algebraic variety in the set of polynomials over a field of coefficients (usually the rationals or the reals) and you want to know if the intersection of that collection of varieties is nonempty.  Equivalently, by the nullstellensatz is the radical of the sum of the ideals corresponding to each variety trivial?  Probably useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636748/is-there-an-easy-criterion-to-determine-whether-given-polynomials-form-a-complet

A brisk introduction to these ideas: https://antonleykin.math.gatech.edu/math4803spr13/BOOK/chapter4.pdf

And to resolve any possible question about my use of "is ... ideal trivial?": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910838/if-v-emptyset-what-does-the-ideal-iv-consist-of

I'm assuming $f$ has degree at most $n-1$? I think you need to strengthen your third condition a bit more. For example the conditions $(0,0,0), (0,0,2), (1,1,2), (1,1,3)$ is satisfied by $f(x)=\frac{1}{6}x^3+kx$ for any $k$. You can (sort of a generalization of the vandermonde matrix) set up a matrix equation of the form $Ma=b$ where $M$ is determined by the $x$ and $k$ coordinates of the list of triples and $b$ is determined by the $y$ coordinates of the triples. We want to solve for $a$, the coefficients of $f$. I think that should give some insight on how to strengthen your third condition.

Specifically if we consider the submatrix from any abirtrary choice of $c$ columns of $M$, it should have at least $c$ nonzero rows. In fact I think you can phrase all of the conditions you have listed so far as necessary conditions for a matrix to be invertible. Idk if they are sufficient in this specific class of matrices. Showing the vandermonde matrix is invertible isn't an easy task and very much relies on the uniformity of its structure. I'm not seeing an easy generalization from that pov at the moment.

What is the purpose of all those backticks? I'd rather see $n$ than n.

@GerryMyerson It is just habit. I changed it.

I apologize, I forgot to specify the degree of $f$ being $n - 1$. I edited it.

You need to restrict the degree of $f$ to be less than $n$ to have any hope of uniqueness. The nicest case of this interpolation problem I'm aware of is the one where you always specify the values of the first $n_i$ derivatives at every point $x_i$ for some $n_i$ (so e.g. if you specify the 3rd derivative you also have to specify the 0th, 1st, and 2nd derivatives). That is, you have some distinct points $x_i$ at which you want to interpolate, and you require that $f$ satisfies
$$\forall k, 0 \le k < n_i : f^{(k)}(x_i) = y_{k, i}$$
for some non-negative integers $n_i$ and some values $y_{k, i}$. Altogether this specifies $n = \sum n_i$ conditions on a polynomial $f$, which we will take to have degree less than $n$ so that it has $n$ coefficients.

Theorem (generalized Lagrange interpolation): The solution to the above interpolation problem exists and is unique.

Proof. Uniqueness is easier. If $f, g$ are two solutions to the interpolation problem then $h = f - g$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n$ such that $h^{(k)}(x_i) = 0$ for $0 \le k < n_i$. This is equivalent to the condition that $h$ is divisible by the polynomials $(x - x_i)^{n_i}$, so $h$ must be divisible by $\prod (x - x_i)^{n_i}$, which has degree $n$, and this is only possible if $h = 0$.
For existence the idea is the same as in Lagrange interpolation: we will argue that for every $i$ and every $0 \le k < n_i$ there exists a polynomial $f_{k, i}(x)$ of degree less than $n$ such that all the first $n_j$ derivatives at $x_j, j \neq i$ vanish and such that all of the first $n_i$ derivatives at $x_i$ vanish except the $k^{th}$ one, which is equal to $1$. Taking linear combinations of these polynomials will solve the interpolation problem; the unique solution must be $f(x) = \sum_{k, i} y_{k, i} f_{k, i}(x)$.
So let's see how this works. We'll consider polynomials of the form
$$h(x) = g(x) \prod_{j \neq i} (x - x_j)^{n_j}$$
which are guaranteed to satisfy $h^{(k)}(x_j) = 0$ for $0 \le k < n_j$ (translate $x_j$ to the origin to see this). $\deg h$ is less than $n$ iff $\deg g$ is less than $n_i$, so we have exactly an $n_i$-dimensional space of polynomials to work with to fit $n_i$ equations, which means this strategy has a hope of working.
For fixed $i$, which we now suppress from the notation for simplicity, consider the polynomials $h_k(x) = (x - x_i)^k \prod_{j \neq i} (x - x_j)^{n_j}$ for $0 \le \ell < n_i$. By construction the derivatives of these polynomials at $x_i$ satisfy
$$h^{(\ell)}_k(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } 0 \le \ell < k \\
 \neq 0 & \text{ if } \ell = k \end{cases}$$
(again, translate $x_i$ to the origin to see this), and this is already enough to conclude. Formally, taking the first $n_i$ derivatives at $x_i$ is a linear transformation from our $n_i$-dimensional vector space $V$ spanned by the polynomials $h_k$ to the $n_i$-dimensional vector space $K^{n_i}$ (where $K$ is our base field which is arbitrary in this argument), and we've exhibited a basis of $V$ in which this linear transformation is triangular with nonzero coefficients on the diagonal. This means it must be invertible, which means the interpolating polynomials $f_{k, i}(x)$ exist and are given by the inverse of this linear transformation applied to the standard basis of $K^{n_i}$.
Explicitly this means we can construct the interpolating polynomial $f_{n_i-1, i}(x)$ as a multiple of $h_{n_i-1}(x)$, the interpolating polynomial $f_{n_i-2, i}(x)$ as a linear combination of $h_{n_i-1}(x), h_{n_i-2}(x)$, and so on; we are just solving the triangular system of equations necessary to match the values of the derivatives. $\Box$
Edit: We can make the existence argument shorter at the cost of making it even less explicit. The uniqueness argument shows that the linear map from the vector space of polynomials of degree less than $n$ to $K^n$ given by taking all of the derivatives we are trying to interpolate is injective. But this is a linear map between two vector spaces of the same dimension, so if it's injective then it's invertible, and its inverse solves the interpolation problem. $\Box$
This argument is unfortunately notationally heavy but the idea is that we just work one point at a time. It would be instructive to work through the special case that $x_i$ is the only point at which we want to interpolate to see what it's saying in that case.
Without this condition on the derivatives we want to interpolate at, it is not generally going to be possible to get uniqueness just by restricting the degree of $f$, and Alan Abraham gives an example in the comments. The proof of uniqueness above crucially requires that we consider all the first $n_i$ derivatives at any given point for some $n_i$. Basically the issue is that we have a very nice description of the vector space of polynomials such that the first $n_i$ derivatives vanish at $x_i$, since it is exactly the subspace of polynomials divisible by $(x - x_i)^{n_i}$, and we have a very good handle on polynomial divisibility. But if we skip specifying a single derivative this is no longer true and we have to do some harder linear algebra I don't understand.
